# Why does my method for collision detection not work?

Tags: java, collision-detection

I understand the basis of collision detection and have developed my way (as far as I know) for collision detection. However, it does not seem to be working. What I have done is instead of drawing full rectangles around sprites, shapes, and other objects, I simply made methods that draw lines (very thin rectangles) on all sides of the object, left, right, top, and bottom.

The methods that draw the thin rectangles on the left,right,top, and bottom of the specified sprites. This is probably not the best way to do collision, but this is what I have, and am open to all ideas and different solutions!

Note: The(int)(x-Game.getCamera().getX()),(int)(y + height -Game.getCamera().getY()), is simply for the camera, so when the player moves, the trees (in my case the object I want to collide with) do not move with him

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
return new Rectangle((int)(x-Game.getCamera().getX()),
        (int)(y + height - Game.getCamera().getY()),width,height-height);
}

public  Rectangle getBoundsTop() {
return new Rectangle((int)(x-Game.getCamera().getX()),
        (int)(y- Game.getCamera().getY()),width,height-height);
}

public  Rectangle getBoundsRight() {
return new Rectangle((int)(x + width -Game.getCamera().getX()),
        (int)(y - Game.getCamera().getY()),width - width,height);

}

public  Rectangle getBoundsLeft() {
return new Rectangle((int)(x -Game.getCamera().getX()),
        (int)(y- Game.getCamera().getY()),width - width,height);

    }
```

Actual collision CHECKING (in player class)-

```
if(getBounds().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsTop())) {
    //What happens when they collide
    //When the bottom of the player collides with the top of the tree.
    }
if(getBoundsTop().intersects(treeTile.getBounds())) {
    //What happens when they collide
    //When the top of the player collides with the bottom of the tree

    }
if(getBoundsRight().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsLeft())) {
    //What happens when they collide
    //when the right side of the player collides with the left of the 
    //tree
    }
if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsRight())) {
    //What happens when they collide
    //When the left of the player collides with the right of the tree
    }
```

I appreciate all the help I can get

Here is collision and movement code-

```
for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        Square handle = handler.object.get(i);
    if (getBounds().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsTop())) {
            handle.setvelY(-1);

    }
    if (getBoundsTop().intersects(treeTile.getBounds())) {
            handle.setvelY(0);

    }
    if (getBoundsRight().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsLeft())) {
            handle.setvelX(0);
    }
    if (getBoundsLeft().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsRight())) {
            handle.setvelX(0);

    }
    }
```

Movement-

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int code = e.getKeyCode();



    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        Square handle = handler.object.get(i);

        if (handle.getId() == ObjectId.Zelda) {


            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                handle.right();
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                handle.left();
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                handle.up();
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                handle.down();
            }
 }
```

My new collision idea -

```
boolean walkRight = true;
boolean walkLeft = true;
boolean walkDown = true;
boolean walkUp = true;
public void tick() {

    if(walkRight == true) {
        velX = 2;

    }if(walkLeft == true) {
        velX = -2;

    }if(walkDown == true) {
        velY = 2;

    }if(walkUp == true) {
        velY = -2;
    }


if (getBounds().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsTop())) {
       walkDown = false;

}
if (getBoundsTop().intersects(treeTile.getBounds())) {
        walkUp = false;
}
if (getBoundsRight().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsLeft())) {
        walkRight = false;

}
if (getBoundsLeft().intersects(treeTile.getBoundsRight())) {
        walkLeft = false;

}
```

Something like this, not exactly, it is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using 1 instead of width - width and height - height ?

I think these evaluating to 0 for the width / height is causing the intersects function to fail.

EDIT

I think you're over complicating this. If you just have one big collision box, instead of four small ones, then where ever you're moving your player, you can

```
// Square previousPosition = currentPosition
// do move player code, which presumably updates the currentPosition
// loop through all the trees you have
//    if the player is colliding with a tree
//        currentPosition = previousPosition
```

This should handle the player colliding with any side of the tree, since we just move them back to where they were previously.

Comment: @Maker M It works by replacing the variables with 1. Although when  the player walks into a tree at any direction, the player stops (because I set the velocity x or y to 0 depending on where the player collides), and then he is able to walk through the tree, barley a second after he has stopped.

Comment: Without seeing your collision handling and movement code, it's hard to find the issue, but somethings to consider - Do you need to know which side of the tree the player is colliding with ? If you don't, then you can just do playerRectangle.intersects(treeRectangle), and if they're intersecting, move the player back to the position they were in previously.  (Currently, your collision code is setting the velocity to 0 after they have collided, but they're still colliding, so you have to separate them somehow. Moving the player back to the previous position is the easiest way I think.)

Comment: I have put the movement and collision code, if there is anything that you do not understand, I will be happy to clarify. Yes I do need to know which side of the tree the player is colliding with, what happens is, I have set collision bounds for each side of the sprites, left, right, up, and down, and when those collision bounds intersect with the tree collision bounds, then I want the player to not be able to move in the collided direction.

Comment: Is _Square_ a custom class ? Does handle.right() move them a set amount ? The easiest way of managing this might be to do handle.left() if your player collides with the left side of the tree, handle.right() if they collide with the right side etc., so they move back in the direction they came from, and are then no longer colliding with the tree. So your game loop would be ordered by 'MovePlayer() HandleCollisions() DrawGameWorld()'.

Comment: Yes Square is a custom abstract class that contains a number of getters and setters; setX,setY,setvelX, setvelY (velocity). And for the handle.left() and such; it is just changing the velocity to either negative or positive 2 depending on whether the player is moving up, down, left, or right. I can show you what I have written, for clarity. I have just tested your above solution, and it works fine. However, when the player holds down a key and walks towards the tree, the left(),right(),up(),or down() method is called, and then the player walks right through the tree.

Comment: I thought of using a boolean and when the player collides, the boolean's state will change;

Comment: I updated my answer with some pseudo code on how I think this should be done. Your approach seems overly complicated. Give my way a shot and see if it works!

Comment: Ok, so I followed your pseudo code (just with a few edits of my own), and it worked great! So thank you very much for the help! How can I mark this question as "Answered"?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! There should be a checkmark somewhere on my answer, possibly below the up / down arrows ? I'm actually not entirely sure where it is...